# jQuery UI sortable on slider solution

Tags: jquery-ui, slider, jquery-ui-sortable

I currently have implemented jQuery UI sortable on my list of items

```
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
...
</ul>
```

To that list I have slider which shows only X number of items and rest can be shown by clicking next or previous buttons.
I tried to add sort parameter to sortable constructor and call those methods, but here is the thing. The container showNext and showPrevious methods do some jQuery animation and destroy first node etc. and I think that workaround would be easier and leave those methods for buttons.
How would you suggest to make this happen: When I start to reorder elements and moving to the end of the list, the list shows next element and places currently dragged after that, but doesn't stop dragging event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this by making container overflow:hidden and implemented sort(e,ui)

```
sort : function(e, ui) {
//move by modulus
}
```